# Woocommerce set order_status via php and trigger email

Tags: java, php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I wrote a program in Java which fullfills the orders from Woocommerce. After having fullfilled the orders the program changes the order status via sql to completed. The problem is that the ***order-completed-email*** for the customer ***won't be send using this way***.

How I can change the `order_status` from orders which are listed in my database using php?

*I think the customer order completed email notification will be sent, once the order_status will be changed via php.*

With my java program I have the possibilities to write/read to my database and to open websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making the order completed, your application in Java could create a custom field for the order with a `meta_key` like *(for example)* `'_need_status_update'` with any value (like `'1'` for example).

Now the hooked function below will check *(every time when someone is browsing the web site)* for this particular custom field *(`'meta_key' = '_need_status_update'`)*.

If the custom field is found, it will:

- delete this custom field (meta data)
- update the order status to "completed"
- trigger the email notification to the customer

The hooked function:

```
add_action( 'init', 'check_orders_update_status' );
function check_orders_update_status(){
    global $wpdb;

    $meta_key = '_need_status_update';

    // SQL query Get orders Ids that have a meta key like '_need_status_update'
    $orders_ids = $wpdb->get_col( "
        SELECT pm.post_id
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm
        WHERE pm.meta_key LIKE '$meta_key'
    " );

    if( count($orders_ids) > 0 ){
        foreach( $orders_ids as $order_id) {
            // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
            $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

            // Delete the meta data '_need_status_update'
            delete_post_meta( $order_id, $meta_key );

            // Updating Order status (will send "Customer order completed" email notification
            $order->update_status('completed');
        }
    }
}
```

This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

The code is tested and works.

**Change needs in your Java App:** 
You just need to change the behavior of your app, that will add instead in wp_postmeta for a given existing order ID, a custom field like:

- `meta_key` Like `'_need_status_update'` *(can be renamed at your convenience in both sides)*
- `meta_value` Like `'1'`

Once this will be done everything will be automated.

Last thing, the SQL requests in the function that checks orders is very light…

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer! I used to try it in this way but I receive the following error when I open my page: **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function update_status() on boolean**. Do you have an idea what the mistake is?

Comment: @PhilippRitter I have tested the code adding before to an existing order the custom field (manually in the database table wp_postmeta)…  Then when I browse any page, the custom meta data is deleted, order status changed to completed and email triggered, without any error. The Order need to be a real WC_Order… If not the method update_status will fail throwing a similar error.

Comment: @PhilippRitter I have just retested, my code and it just works… So there is certainly a problem with the order itself… If you are generating them from your App, there is something missing. I am testing under last WooCommerce version and last Wordpress version.

Comment: I made a mistake in my java program. I put the order_id in meta_value and not in post_id - sorry! Now I have tested the code again and it works perfectly! Thank you very much for your answer! Philipp

Answer (score 0):

How we did this is by creating a plugin which replace the original WooCommerce order statuses and email behaviors.

Here's how:

1. If you need to add/remove default order statuses, you can do so by hooking to `wc_order_statuses` hook, and return an array of valid order statuses by your business process, and do `register_post_status()` in `init` hook.
2. Email sending on status change actions are defined by the email classes. They can be altered by hooking to `woocommerce_email_classes` hook. Below is a snippet of what we did:

   ```
   /*
    * @hook woocommerce_email_classes
    * @param WC_Email[] $emails
    * @return WC_Email[]
    */
   public static function initCustomEmails($emails) {

       // Replace all emails with our own

       global $wp_filter;
       unset($wp_filter['woocommerce_order_status_completed_notification']);
       $emails = [
           'WC_Email_Customer_New_Account' => include('emails/classes/WC_Email_Customer_New_Account.php'),
           'WC_Email_Customer_Order_Verify' => include('emails/classes/WC_Email_Customer_Order_Verify.php'),
           ...
       ];

       return $emails;
   }
   ```

And below is a snippet of the referenced email class:

```
if ( ! class_exists('WC_Email_Customer_Order_Verify') ) {

    class WC_Email_Customer_Order_Verify extends WC_Email {

        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        function __construct() {
            // Triggers for this email
            add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_order-verify', array( $this, 'trigger' ) );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', array( $this, 'trigger' ) );

            // Call parent constructor
            parent::__construct();
        }

        /**
         * Trigger.
         * @param WC_Order|int $wcOrder
         * @throws InvalidOrderException
         */
        function trigger( $wcOrder ) {
            if ( ! $this->is_enabled() || ! $this->get_recipient() ) {
                return;
            }

            $this->send( $this->get_recipient(), $this->get_subject(), $this->get_content(), $this->get_headers(), $this->get_attachments() );
        }

        /**
         * get_content_html function.
         *
         * @access public
         * @return string
         */
        function get_content_html() {
            ob_start();
            wc_get_template( $this->template_html, array(
                'order'         => $this->object,
                'orderDetails'  => $this->orderDetails,
                'sent_to_admin' => false,
                'plain_text'    => false
            ) );
            return ob_get_clean();
        }

        /**
         * get_content_plain function.
         *
         * @access public
         * @return string
         */
        function get_content_plain() {
            ob_start();
            wc_get_template( $this->template_plain, array(
                'order'         => $this->object,
                'orderDetails'  => $this->orderDetails,
                'sent_to_admin' => false,
                'plain_text'    => true
            ) );
            return ob_get_clean();
        }
    }

}

return new WC_Email_Customer_Order_Verify();
```

The trigger and what to do when it is triggered is defined above. 
Hope this helps.